# Translation of "Я ничего не могу с этим сделать"...?

Tags: падежи

I came across this phrase in a Russian reader I purchased and translated the phrase to mean,

> I cannot do nothing with this.

The translation given by the author is

> I can't do anything about it.

I checked the uses of the preposition "с" with the instrumental case in a Russian Grammar book, which stated the following uses:

> (a) *with* in the sense of together with, along with, accompanied by
>
> (b) to indicate an accompanying characteristic or attribute of someone
>   or something
>
> (c) to indicate manner
>
> Also used with a list of verbs.
>
> ...

Is this phrase an idiomatic expression, or am I missing a case of use with the preposition с + instrumental? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another meaning of the Russian preposition "с" when used with the instrumental case is expressing associations, rather than spacial or temporal closeness. English "with" expresses a similar meaning in

> I don't have anything to do **with** this. (я тут ни при чём)

Note that the meaning changes based on context: compare

> Я не знаю что делать с лопатой. (I don't know what to do with a shovel.)

and

> Я не знаю что делать с головной болью. (I don't know what to do *about* my headache.)

P.S. I am assuming that your question is not about the double negative in the reader's translation: that's commonplace in Russian - "**ни**чего **не** могу сделать" becomes "cannot do anything".

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it corresponds then to the last sentence given in the Russian Grammar book that you quoted ("it is also used with a list of verbs"). The preposition *c* is used along with the verb *делать*: "to do something about/with ..." is "делать что с + (instr.)", which is indeed present in the phrase in question.